# MySQL Tuning - too much SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END) needed

Tags: mysql, optimization, case-when

I have big table

```
customer_id ; category ; quantity  ;budget     ; profit
      15570 ; garden   ;  1.000,00 ;  1.325,00 ;     59,94
      17090 ; cars     ;  9.600,00 ; 11.671,76 ;   -409,28
      10360 ; cars     ; 12.110,00 ;  3.981,60 ;    961,97
      10360 ; garden   ; 10.150,00 ;  4.828,95 ;    872,27
      16460 ; toys     ; 24.000,00 ; 19.656,00 ;    991,00
      18260 ; metal    ; 24.000,00 ; 17.688,00 ; -1.131,52
...
```

and this query to find quantity, budget, profit for each category

```
SELECT customer_id,

(SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'garden' THEN budget END)) as budget1, 
(SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'garden' THEN quantity END)) as quantity1,
(SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'garden' THEN profit END)) as profit1,

(SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'cars' THEN budget END)) as budget2, 
(SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'cars' THEN quantity END)) as quantity2,
(SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'cars' THEN profit END)) as profit2,

(SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'toys' THEN budget END)) as budget3, 
(SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'toys' THEN quantity END)) as quantity3,
(SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'toys' THEN profit END)) as profit3,

(SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'metal' THEN budget END)) as budget4, 
(SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'metal' THEN quantity END)) as quantity4,
(SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'metal' THEN profit END)) as profit4

SUM(budget) as budget, 
SUM(quantity) as quantity,
SUM(profit) as profit

FROM `sales` GROUP BY customer_id
```

Is it possible to make the query faster (more efficient)?

Comment: You can try an index on `customer_id`, but I don't think that will help.  MySQL does not have many options for optimizing aggregation queries.

Comment: Provide sample data also, which can help identify if there is another way to achieve same results.

Comment: Presumably (customer_id,category) is your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it makes much difference to performance, but I would run the query as...

```
 SELECT customer_id
      , category
      , SUM(quantity) total_quantity
      , SUM(budget) total_budget
      , SUM(profit) total_profit 
   FROM sales 
  GROUP 
     BY customer_id
      , category;
```

...and handle any remaining display issues in the presentation layer.

Comment: Since it is the whole table, _adding_ an index won't help.  Having `PRIMARY KEY(customer_id,category)`, in that order, should avoid the filesort.